# deny access to URL- nginx regex

Tags: regex, url, nginx

What regex would I use to deny every URL using "?":

Ex. domain.com/? and domain.com/?p=1224

```
location (need regex){
deny all;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? Why do you need to block parameter passing?

Comment: It also seems like that won't work (http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,70190,70376) anyway, but I don't use nginx, so I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `\?` would do what you want, `^\?` is the reverse expression.